# conky stops when disconnected from network

Tags: linux, gnu, conky

I have a pretty decent sized conkyrc, you can see it here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spravo13/dotfiles/master/conkyrc-desktop

I have a problem where when I disconnect from the internet the whole conky freezes. I understand if the features that require the internet for info stop, but not the whole conky. Anyone know if there is a setting so everything that doesn't require the internet will continue to run? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried your conky file and disconnected, but it didn't freeze. Have you tried deleting the last few lines with the `curl` commands to see if it still freezes?

Comment: @weletonne Thank you so much for your response! I just tested my conky with and without the curl at the bottom and now it's working disconnected for the internet too, even with the curl commands. Must have been just something that was coincidental or I disconnected while it was fetching data.

Either way, I'm glad it works now.

Thanks again!